# Specific version checking + if and else loop

Tags: puppet

just start puppet. As everyone else knows, starting something is always the most difficult. Well for practice I wanna do the following: I assume I am to put it in init.pp. I did my google search before posting here. Most of them out there do not apply an if/else loop on version checking. Most just ensure a specific version or just ensure => latest.

```
if 'openssl' version == '1.0.2b' or '1.0.2d'
    upgrade to 1.1.1e
else
     do nothing
```

Currently my code looks like this

```
 package { 'openssl':
    if 'openssl' version == '1.0.2b' or '1.0.2d' {
        ensure => '1.1.1e'
    }
    else {
    }
```

I have several problems:

1) I don't think my syntax for the version of openssl is written correctly. When I do simple google search I see people ensuring version of openssl something like this '1.0.1e-15.el6', sometimes it's '1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7' I am confused on determining what's after the '-'

3) How to check version of openssl? I think the syntax if `'openssl' version == "xxxx"` is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your OS you have to find out the full name of the package to install. On a `redhat` like system you can use `yum info openssl` to find out the full package name. You will see something like this:

`[root@puppet-vm ~]# yum info openssl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de
 * extras: mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de
 * updates: mirror.maeh.org
Installed Packages
Name        : openssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 42.el7.9
Size        : 1.5 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Utilities from the general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
License     : OpenSSL
Description : The OpenSSL toolkit provides support for secure communications between
            : machines. OpenSSL includes a certificate management tool and shared
            : libraries which provide various cryptographic algorithms and
            : protocols.`

Where

`Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 42.el7.9`

gives you the information you need.

This is how you can tell puppet to install this specific version of `openssl` or any other package.

`package { 'openssl':
    ensure => '1.0.1e-42.el7.9',
  }`

More detailed information about the package type can be found [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package).

Puppet is not designed to check for  the existance of packages and only upgrade / downgrade them if they fullfill a specific requirement. Puppet is meant to be used for defining how the server should be configured finally.

There are ways to do what you are trying with [exec](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) but this is not how puppet should be used.